# Adobe InDesign 6 not printing booklets to edges of paper, InDesign 5.5 did

Tags: adobe-indesign, cs6, print-design

I printed booklets for my students in InDesign 5.5.  Worked perfect, on US Letter paper I was able to get 2 worksheets per side.  I'd cut them down the middle and have these great packets of worksheets.  I upgraded to InDesign 6 (on both my mac and PC).  And now the printouts don't extend all the way to the right of the paper.  So when I cut the paper, it's a little off and everything's shifted to the left.

There was an update to InDesign 6 the other day, I installed that... no help :(.  Does InDesign 6 no longer print booklets properly?  What can I do aside from downgrading?

Comment: You have you printer set to borderless printing?

Comment: I'm having a hard time visualizing this. Why would you use Booklet rather than just printing spreads, if you're going to cut anyway? If you expand the question a bit, one of us can probably give you an useful answer.

Comment: @Scott - Borderless printing isn't supported by my laser (or any laser AFAIK) and wouldn't matter in this case anyway.  I should've clarified, I don't want prints ALL the way to the edge, just close.

Comment: @AlanGilbertson - I don't know what printing spreads is, but booklet printing is very convenient.  I print, cut and fold over.  Then staple.  For some situations, I use it like a booklet and don't cut, just place a couple staples down the middle.  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: It sounds like you're printing two booklet spreads (a spread is two pages that appear opposite one another in the finished piece) side by side on one sheet, but I don't think that's what you mean. A diagram would help. Knowing the exact finished (folded) size would also help. (5.5x8.5? 4.25x5.5?) There may be an even easier workflow in there, if I could grasp exactly what the end product is.

Comment: @AlanGilbertson - Thanks for the help!  so I really want 5.5x8.5 worksheets printed front and back for students.  The print booklet feature allows me to print all the 5.5x8.5 worksheets on standard (and inexpensive) US Letter paper and then cut them.  Then I simply fold them over and I have all my 5.5x8.5 worksheets in order ready to be stapled.  I also have a catalog I print out and instead of cutting the pages, I just staple down the middle and it really is a booklet.  Does that help?

Comment: @at. - Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: Got this pretty close by outputting to postscript format, then using another adobe product called distiller to translate that to pdf format for booklet pages. Then we print the pdf using adobe acrobat. On our Brother laser and inkjets it's still a little off, but the hewlett packards print this very well. Kind of an ugly process, but we tried pretty much everything else possible...

Answer (score 1):

End-use printers are not precise machines when it comes to pulling paper through them and aligning it. You could print something 100 times and no 2 copies would "line up" exactly. The nature of the machines is such that they can't control precise paper feed alignment without jamming and being unreliable that way. So, most end-use printers have around 1/16" to 1/4" shift when printing.

There's not really a great deal you can do to correct this. You could compensate for the slight shift when printing by *not* designing anything to the edge of a page or which would make any shift more apparent. Large margins are generally very helpful for this sort of thing.

The InDesign versions should not be a factor. If they indeed are, then you need to ensure you've got settings, print drivers, etc all the same between the two versions of InDesign.